# PHP XML options of importing

Tags: php, xml, arrays, import

I'm loading some xml file via `simplexml_load_string`

My code is

`$xml = simplexml_load_string($fileContent, NULL, LIBXML_NOCDATA);`

And it works ok but:

```
<photos>
    <photo>8894133.jpg</photo>
    <photo>8892133.jpg</photo>
</photos>
```

Will be loaded as

```
  'photos' => 
    array (size=1)
      'photo' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string '8894133.jpg' (length=61)
          1 => string '8894133.jpg' (length=61)
```

While 1 'row' only data like:

```
<photos>
    <photo>8894133.jpg</photo>
</photos>
```

Will be loaded like

```
'photos' => 
    array (size=1)
      'photo' => string '892133.jpg' (length=61)
```

And it is not same structure of arrays. As first is `index>array>index>array>index>data`, 2nd is `index>array>index>data`

Is it possible to config loading so singular data will be loaded not dircetly as string, but as 1 element array too so 2nd result would be

```
  'photos' => 
    array (size=1)
      'photo' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '8894133.jpg' (length=61)
```

Comment: You could do that manually for each entry/type you want to ensure loads that way using `is_array` or `gettype` and a little tree traversal, but it would probably be just as much effort as checking for array vs string/whatever data type is now

Comment: You miss the point that those are not arrays (whatever you use to create that output is lying to you), in fact those are magic SimpleXMLElements. They provide an interator of the elements you can convert into an array your own by using [`iterator_to_array`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array).

Answer (score 0):

you should use the xml-Object to get data from node directly. there is no reason to iterate from root-node.

first you load your file with:

```
// create xml-object from file
if(!$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile)) {
   $this->addErrorMessage('XML Objekt could not be loaded from file:'.$xmlFile);
}
```

then you get your data from node directly:

```
//save Data from xml to whatever
foreach ($xml->photo as $newPhoto){
    // create and return object with data
    $myData = $newPhoto;
}
```